# Merge 2 SparseDataFrame with same index/columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 [`pandas.SparseDataFrame`'s](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparsedataframe) in the form

```
A = pd.SparseDataFrame(
    [[a,0,0,b],A
     [0,0,0,c],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,a]])

B = pd.SparseDataFrame(
    [[a,0,0,0],
     [0,0,c,0],
     [0,0,0,c],
     [0,0,0,0]])
```

Those are (labeled) adjacency matrix of subgraphs coming from the same graph (so in same position you can find 0 or the same value: *A[x][y]=B[x][y] for each values!=0*). In other words, value conflicts aren't possible.

I want to merge (*performance wise*) those dataframes, the result should be:

```
[[a,0,0,b],
 [0,0,c,c],
 [0,0,0,c],
 [0,0,0,a]]
```

I'm not clear what's the pandas way to merge 2 Dataframes with the same columns labels.

I see there is [update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) which works as I want, but it edits the calling DataFrame in-place, I don't want that. The only way is a deep-copy and then a merge using update()? As I said, the operation should be performance-wise..

Comment: Is DataFrame work with you ? Or you want to stack with SparseDataFrame

Answer (score 2):

In method 1, 2, and 3, we use sparse matrices from [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.html) There are many kinds of sparse matrices `scipy` support, and I **only** experimented with `coo_matrix`, `csc_matrix`, `csr_matrix`, and `dok_matrix`.

**First**, convert your features/labels to numbers so that we can use some math property: {a to 1, b to 2, and c to 3} in this example. In method 4, you don't need to convert it.

**Method 1**: Use `dok_matrix` and `update` method it contains. `update` can takes an iterable with each element being (idx, value).

```
# to_coo() will make a sparse matrix | todok() will make coo_matrix a dok_matrix
A = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]).to_coo().todok()   
B = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,3], [0,0,0,0]]).to_coo().todok()   

nz = B.nonzero()   # non-zero's indeces from B

# only update when B is non-zero
A.update([((nz[0][i], nz[1][i]), B[nz[0][i], nz[1][i]]) for i in range(len(nz[0]))])

%timeit A.update([((nz[0][i], nz[1][i]), B[nz[0][i], nz[1][i]]) for i in range(len(nz[0]))])
52.2 µs ± 4.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**HOWEVER**, loading it back to pandas will take a long long time than merging! This is true for method 1, 2, and 3. So my 2 cents is that you might want to stick with `scipy.sparse` over `pandas.SparseDataFrame` if speed of merging is your concenr.

```
%timeit pd.SparseDataFrame(A)
3.47 ms ± 319 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Also, `dok_matrix` might be slow in other matrix operations. From my trials, `dok_matrix` is slow in the simple matrix operation as you will see later in method 2 and 3. Nonetheless, only `dok_matrix` has the function `update`. (`dok_matrix` is dictionary based.) **Though this method seems fast, I am guessing that if your matrix is a lot denser, it will be slow to use this method compare to the next method.**

---

**Method 2**: In this method, we take the part in `B - A` that is greater than 0 and multiply it elementwisely with `B` to get the parts in `B` and not in `A`. Seems to be a **little** bit faster than method 4 below.

```
# to_coo() will make a sparse matrix
A = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]).to_coo()   
B = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,3], [0,0,0,0]]).to_coo() 

D = ((-A + B) > 0).multiply(B) + A

%timeit D = ((-A + B) > 0).multiply(B) + A
645 µs ± 25.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using `csc_matrix` will make is slightly faster.

```
A = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]).to_coo().tocsc()
B = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,3], [0,0,0,0]]).to_coo().tocsc()
%timeit  = ((-A + B) > 0).multiply(B) + A    
434 µs ± 84.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

**Method 3**: This method utilizes an equality that `((B-A) + np.abs(B-A))/2` will be what is in `B` but not in `A`. (Same values in `A` and `B` will cancel out and a difference will be doubled. Thus, we divide it by two at the end.)

```
C = ((B - A) + np.abs(B-A))/2 + A

%timeit C = ((B - A) + np.abs(B-A))/2 + A
852 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using `csc_matrix` makes the result faster

```
A = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]).to_coo().tocsc()
B = pd.SparseDataFrame([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,0,0,3], [0,0,0,0]]).to_coo().tocsc()
%timeit C = ((-A + B) + np.abs(B-A))/2 + A   
598 µs ± 42.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

**Method 4**: This is slow, slow, and used for benchmark's purpose. **Another scenario to use this is that you don't need to match each label to an integer.** As you mentioned, we only need to fill in values from `A` when `B == 0`. Thus, you can try `np.where(B == 0, A, B)`, though it returns a dense matrix.

```
A = pd.SparseDataFrame(
    [['a',0,0,'b'],
     [0,0,0,'c'],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,'a']])

B = pd.SparseDataFrame(
    [['a',0,0,0],
     [0,0,'c',0],
     [0,0,0,'c'],
     [0,0,0,0]])

pd.SparseDataFrame(np.where(B == 0, A, B))

%timeit pd.SparseDataFrame(np.where(B == 0, A, B))
7.39 ms ± 454 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note again the first 3 methods all need to translate a sparse matrix back to `SparseDataFrame` if you really need `SparseDataFrame`. This will make the first 3 methods nearly as slow as this method 4.

Takeaways:

- Convert a sparse matrix into a SparseDataFrame might takes a lot longer and lose the advantage of using sparse matrix. One can just stay with sparse matrix rather than SparseDataFrame.
- If your matrix is dense, you might want to favor method 2 over method 1. (my hypothesis)
- Use [`csc_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix) or [`csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) or [`dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix) rather than [`coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) in this particular case. However, I think different sparse matrix will be useful in different scenarios. Time it yourself for you particular application!

---

I did not take into account the time to transfer from pd.SparseDataFrame to sparse matrix, though. It is not trivial, and will be discussed here.

```
%timeit A.to_coo()   # takes most of the time
410 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
A_coo = A.to_coo()
%timeit A_coo.todok() 
17.3 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)   
%timeit A_coo.tocsc() 
49.9 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As seen from the experiment above, `to_coo()` takes most of the time and it is used in all 1, 2 and 3 methods. Thus, it does not change the overall speed comparison of these methods. Also, these are only tested in small data. Please do test on your data beforehand as when data is larger, the behaviors should be different.

Comment: 7 ms for a tiny dataset is hardly encouraging. By the way, you should time commands on much larger data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for the comments. Guess I will put it aside for now. Some other works coming :<